# Corrplot visualization in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Below is the correlation data which is required to build a correlation chart. However when i build the chart, the chart does not appear in well visualized form. I tried different way, but could no produce a good visualization.

```
> dput(N)
structure(c(1, 1, 0.124125105184851, -0.0075828943662825, -0.041940562943062, 
-0.0075828943662825, -0.0075828943662825, -0.0467026264189617, 
-0.0392551254498135, 0.00109906505725404, -0.0385514512522729, 
-0.0838241725271613, -0.0125518961643925, 1, 1, 0.124125105184851, 
-0.0075828943662825, -0.041940562943062, -0.0075828943662825, 
-0.0075828943662825, -0.0467026264189617, -0.0392551254498135, 
0.00109906505725404, -0.0385514512522729, -0.0838241725271613, 
-0.0125518961643925, 0.124125105184851, 0.124125105184851, 1, 
0.991296820432301, -0.0279280725452435, 0.991296820432301, 0.991296820432301, 
-0.0518874418247448, -0.065605070072127, -0.0109413593165059, 
-0.0348115490217691, -0.0706758851320097, -0.00672761890695831, 
-0.0075828943662825, -0.0075828943662825, 0.991296820432301, 
1, -0.0225805964130929, 1, 1, -0.0460942119972777, -0.0609064271344148, 
-0.0111721308556704, -0.0299671607008791, -0.0601035601205344, 
-0.00511457437946779, -0.041940562943062, -0.041940562943062, 
-0.0279280725452435, -0.0225805964130929, 1, -0.0225805964130929, 
-0.0225805964130929, 0.160600439234611, 0.0726539093638991, -0.0262498855556489, 
0.0264220195066021, 0.490039350007889, 0.0973879504867165, -0.0075828943662825, 
-0.0075828943662825, 0.991296820432301, 1, -0.0225805964130929, 
1, 1, -0.0460942119972777, -0.0609064271344148, -0.0111721308556704, 
-0.0299671607008791, -0.0601035601205344, -0.00511457437946779, 
-0.0075828943662825, -0.0075828943662825, 0.991296820432301, 
1, -0.0225805964130929, 1, 1, -0.0460942119972777, -0.0609064271344148, 
-0.0111721308556704, -0.0299671607008791, -0.0601035601205344, 
-0.00511457437946779, -0.0467026264189617, -0.0467026264189617, 
-0.0518874418247448, -0.0460942119972777, 0.160600439234611, 
-0.0460942119972777, -0.0460942119972777, 1, 0.924946783481982, 
-0.0215791519475115, -0.127970106908766, 0.160040350913825, 0.276622113066542, 
-0.0392551254498135, -0.0392551254498135, -0.065605070072127, 
-0.0609064271344148, 0.0726539093638991, -0.0609064271344148, 
-0.0609064271344148, 0.924946783481982, 1, -0.0326673838194843, 
-0.0934909502709286, 0.121207258775647, 0.3084625911903, 0.00109906505725404, 
0.00109906505725404, -0.0109413593165059, -0.0111721308556704, 
-0.0262498855556489, -0.0111721308556704, -0.0111721308556704, 
-0.0215791519475115, -0.0326673838194843, 1, 0.0128506013012152, 
-0.0472406075162176, -0.0148905732434414, -0.0385514512522729, 
-0.0385514512522729, -0.0348115490217691, -0.0299671607008791, 
0.0264220195066021, -0.0299671607008791, -0.0299671607008791, 
-0.127970106908766, -0.0934909502709286, 0.0128506013012152, 
1, -0.164612931683442, -0.0329237273761003, -0.0838241725271613, 
-0.0838241725271613, -0.0706758851320097, -0.0601035601205344, 
0.490039350007889, -0.0601035601205344, -0.0601035601205344, 
0.160040350913825, 0.121207258775647, -0.0472406075162176, -0.164612931683442, 
1, 0.183581689836611, -0.0125518961643925, -0.0125518961643925, 
-0.00672761890695831, -0.00511457437946779, 0.0973879504867165, 
-0.00511457437946779, -0.00511457437946779, 0.276622113066542, 
0.3084625911903, -0.0148905732434414, -0.0329237273761003, 0.183581689836611, 
1), .Dim = c(13L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(c("INV_THERAPY_DESCRIPTION", 
"THERAPY2013ROLLUP", "Inv_count", "denial_control", "deni_aging", 
"denial_No_denial", "denial_Non_control", "InvAmt_Avg", "Tot_pay_Avg", 
"WO_percent", "Inv_aging_avg", "AR_aging_avg", "Denial_amount_avg"
), c("INV_THERAPY_DESCRIPTION", "THERAPY2013ROLLUP", "Inv_count", 
"denial_control", "deni_aging", "denial_No_denial", "denial_Non_control", 
"InvAmt_Avg", "Tot_pay_Avg", "WO_percent", "Inv_aging_avg", "AR_aging_avg", 
"Denial_amount_avg")))
```

Below is the code:

```
plot1=corrplot(N,title = "Correlation Plot", method = "square", mar = c(0,0,0,0), outline = T, addgrid.col = "darkgray", order="original", addrect = 10,rect.lwd = 10, rect.col = "black",cl.pos = "b", tl.col = "indianred4", tl.cex = 1, cl.cex = 1)
```

And i recieved the below warning message too:

Warning message:

```
In corrplot(N, title = "Correlation Plot", method = "square", mar = c(0,  :
  Not been able to calculate text margin, please try again with a clean new empty window using {plot.new(); dev.off()} or reduce tl.cex
```

Comment: Maximize the plot window if you are using RStudio. Can you show desired sample output?

Comment: I wanted to use the chart output in my ppt. However the output is so small that, i cannot visualize it properly. Is there any way to adjust in code so that i can get a better visualization and snip it out for my presentation

Comment: Make you variable names short. Like `INV_THERAPY_DESCRIPTION` may be replaced by `ITD`.